# Is it true in an arbitrary field that $-1$ is a sum of two squares iff it is a sum of three squares?

Tags: field-theory

Here's a statement from Lam's *First Course in Noncommutative Rings*. (Paraphrased)

> Let $k$ be a field. Then the following conditions are equivalent. $$(\forall a,b,c,d\in k)\;\;(a,b,c,d)\neq 0\implies a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2\neq 0;\tag 1$$ $$-1\text{ is not a sum of two squares.}\tag2$$

I can't prove this fact. If I replace $(2)$ with

> $$-1\text{ is not a sum of three squares,}\tag3$$

then the equivalence between $(1)$ and $(3)$ is easy to prove. Indeed, suppose $(1)$ is false. Then we may assume without loss of generality that there are $a,b,c,d\in k$ with $a\neq 0$ such that $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=0.$$ But then $$-1=\left(\frac ba\right)^2+\left(\frac ca\right)^2+\left(\frac da\right)^2,$$

and so $(3)$ is false. Conversely, if $(3)$ is false, then there exist $x,y,z\in k$ such that $$-1=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ and therefore $$0=x^2+y^2+z^2+1^2,$$ which means that $(1)$ is false.

I can also prove $(1)\implies (2).$ Suppose $(2)$ is false. Then $$-1=x^2+y^2,$$ whence $$0=x^2+y^2+1^2+0^2,$$ which implies that $(1)$ is false.

But I can't prove $(2)\implies (1)$ and I'm starting to suspect that it may actually be false. But I can't find a counterexample either. It would require finding a field in which $-1$ is a sum of three squares but not a sum of two squares. But in finite fields, every element is a sum of two squares, as proven [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Every_element_of_a_finite_field_is_expressible_as_a_sum_of_two_squares). In the subfields of $\mathbb R$ on the other hand, $-1$ is not a sum of three squares. And in $\mathbb C,$ it is a sum of two squares: $-1=0^2+i^2.$ In general, an example cannot be algebraically closed, which leaves me with the fields of rational functions as the only other fields I know. Also, the example cannot have characteristic $2$ as then $-1=1=1^2+0^2.$

**Edit:** The theorem Gerry Myerson cites in his answer is proven [here](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~stanovsk/skoly/ps2010/prezentace/moconja.pdf). A Wikipedia article on the Stufe is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_%28algebra%29). Both links have been given by joriki in the comments.

Comment: This is an example of a post which is well written. I have been discussing this with the user on chat. I did not have this clear frame in my mind--that I read this post makes me organise what I know. +1 for the question...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\: -1 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2\:$ then either $\rm\:c^2 = -1\:$ or $\rm\:(a^2+b^2)/(c^2+1) = -1,\:$ which may be rewritten as a sum of two squares, since such sums $\ne 0$  form a *group*, using [Brahmagupta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) for  multiplication, and inversion via $\rm\ 0\ne z = x^2\! + y^2\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:1/z = (x/z)^2 + (y/z)^2.$

**Remark** $\ $ The proof [generalizes.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_%28algebra%29)  Replacing the Brahmagupta composition identity by identities discovered by Pfister for quadratic forms in $\rm\:2^n\:$ variables, the proof shows that if $-1$ is a sum of $\rm\:m\:$ squares in a field, then the least value of $\rm\:m\:$ is necessarily a power of $2$, which is called the *level* (*Stufe* in German) of the field. Further, every power of $2$ is the level of some field.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was having a bit of trouble lessening the generality of Pfister's argument given in a comment by joriki. Now everything is clear!

Answer (score 19):

The "stufe" of a field is the smallest $m$ such that $-1$ can be expressed as a sum of $m$ squares. It is a theorem of Pfister that the stufe (if it exists) is always a power of 2.

Comment: Thank you! So if I understand this correctly, Lam's statement is correct. Is is difficult to prove? It would be strange for Lam to make such a statement without proof if it requires advanced field theory...

Comment: There's a proof [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/pfister.pdf). There's also a [German Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_%28Algebra%29) on the "Stufe", but it presupposes some of the facts about Pfister forms that the other text proves.

Comment: @joriki Thank you very much for the links. I can't quite see the proof of Gerry Meyerson's statement in the first one. (I can't read German so I can't use the second one unfortunately...)

Comment: @ymar: Yes, sorry, I just realized that that paper contains only a part of [this slide show](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~stanovsk/skoly/ps2010/prezentace/moconja.pdf) that has the whole proof (part III beginning on p. 81). I was trying to avoid linking to a slide show :-)

Comment: I'm sorry Gerry Myerson for misspelling you name in the previous comment.

Comment: @joriki It looks like it's the same link as before. :)

Comment: @ymar: Sorry, I thought I'd pasted the other one :-) I've corrected it.

Comment: There's an [English Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfister_form) on Pfister forms, and it cites Lam (2004), *Introduction to quadratic forms over fields*. So that might explain why Lam found this obvious enough to use without proof ;-)

Comment: Random fact: "Stufe" is the German word for "step", though it sometimes is also used similar to "level".

Comment: I've created an [English Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albrecht_Pfister_%28mathematician%29) on Albrecht Pfister (translated from the German article).

Comment: @joriki May I add your link to the question so it's not hidden in a comment?

Comment: @ymar: Sure, go ahead. I'm also translating the German Wikipedia article on Stufe; I'll let you know when it's done.

Comment: @ymar: Here's the new English Wikipedia article on [Stufe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stufe_%28algebra%29).